# Get Rid of Google Play Services

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, insufficient-memory

I am using Micromax A80 with Android A80 from last two years. (Android Ginger bread, RAM of just 256MB)

From last two weeks **Google Play services** application is taking too much memory and phone gives error message like insufficient memory  to work.

How to get rid of this problem ?

Is it safe to un-install **Google Play Service** App itself ?

Comment: Whether or not it's safe to uninstall depends on how you use your device. Do you use any of Google's services?

Comment: What are google services ? Can you explain ?

Comment: Anything made by Google. Gmail, Google Maps, the Play Store, etc etc. Any apps made by Google will break if you uninstall Google Play Services.

Comment: Yes, i am using play store (not using maps, gmail).

Comment: So i cant UN-install google play services. Any other solutions to my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get rid of the Google Play Services app would be to root your phone. However,  before even going there, know that any Google App requires Google Play Services and would not work without it.  Google Play Services is essentially an API for all of the Google Apps.  Without the API, the apps would be useless.

A better solution than uninstalling such an important app is to buy a MicroSD Card.  They are extremely inexpensive and are only around $15.00.  Your phone supports up to 32 GB of expansion, so you would definitely have enough room for the app afterwards.  Then root your phone, download Titanium Backup and convert Google Services to a user app. After that, use Link2SD to move it to your SD card.

Comment: i have already 32 GB SD card, i have 16 GB free space in that, but phone memory is too low. Thats the reason for all the problems.

Comment: I know this was a while ago, but I just saw your comment.  You can transfer apps onto the SD Card once you root